Are there really over 400 rooms in Slumberland?
When completing the Demo House of Glider Pro (1994), a message appears that claims that another house in the game, Slumberland, has “over 400 rooms”:

An article I found on MacScene, Dreaming of a Thousand-Room House: The History and Making of Glider, affirms this claim, offering a more precise number “403”:

Slumberland, […] [t]he default house in Glider PRO, [includes] a whopping 403 rooms

Personally, I can finish Slumberland (collect all 6 stars), but I can’t find anything like that many rooms.

I’ve mapped out all the rooms that I have found, and numbered them into a sequential order: 1–280.
First building

Second building and Graveyard

Third building and Sewer

Basement

Note: I can see some empty-looking rooms (marked with a “?”) on either side of the basement (5 in total) that I don’t know how to access. Is it possible to get to these rooms?
Treehouse

Final building

Note:  There are a couple of rooms (marked with a “†”), titled No and Coincidence, right near the end that I can get to, but can’t get out of alive.

Adding all these together: 280 + 2 + 5 = 287. Obviously, this is still well short of 400.
Am I really missing over 100 rooms; are there truly “over 400” rooms in Slumberland? Where would they be on my map, and how can I get to them?

Try to check this video, maybe you can discover rooms you missed

@pinckerman Thanks, I actually watched that video yesterday. Disappointingly, it’s not (as the title suggests) “complete”. It’s a rather clumsy splicing of some not-particularly-clean runs. And the high score at the end show that they only visited 240 rooms.

I love the hand-drawn and hand-counted maps.  This is a lovely achievement just to be prepared to ask this question.

beautiful handwriting

There's an open source version of Glider PRO called Aerofoil (see https://github.com/elasota/Aerofoil), and I poked around the source code a bit. You can unlock the maps to let you view them in the house editor by holding the option/alt key while clicking the "brain" option in the settings window.
Adding up the tallies of the screenshots below there are 383 rooms in the file, at least from the game's point of view. Many of them are inaccessible, though. I went through the level editor and checked all the rooms not on your map, and I don't see any way to get to them. I think you found them all!
Building 1: 58

“ssalG gnikooL”: 9

Building 2: 53

Graveyard: 15

Building 3: 56

Basement & Sewer: 81

Treehouse: 30

Building 4: 81

Metadata for confirmation:


I think only reason these extra rooms are in the level is because you can see them in the peripheries of neighbouring rooms.

The Space room (room 30 in my map) is called “ssalG gnikooL” and is only accessible through Ozma of Oz’s magic picture (in “Looking Glass”, room 29).
